# ReturnType on a callback in a nested property doesn't work

Tags: typescript

The code below explains issue better than words. It seems to me that it should work, but for some reason it doesn't. What's going on here?

```
interface Types {
    'type1': boolean,
    'type2': string,
}

type TypesCallbacks = {
    [key in keyof Types]: (object: any) => Types[key];
};

class TypeProvider {

    private callbackMap: TypesCallbacks = {
        type1: (object) => false,
        type2: (object) => 'test',
    };

    public runTypeCallback<T extends keyof TypesCallbacks>(id: T): ReturnType<TypesCallbacks[T]> {
        const callback = this.callbackMap[id];

        return callback('zz');
             //^^^^^^^^
             //There is an error here
    }

    public getCallback<T extends keyof TypesCallbacks>(id: T): TypesCallbacks[T] {
        return this.callbackMap[id];
               //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               //But this works! Which is proven below.
    }

}
const provider: TypeProvider = new TypeProvider();

const booleanValue: boolean = provider.runTypeCallback('type1');
const stringValue: string = provider.runTypeCallback('type2');


const booleanCallback: (object: any) => boolean = provider.getCallback('type1');
const stringCallback: (object: any) => string = provider.getCallback('type2');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#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-psjkIoaUml0x46ZqYJmFFmKiXSuUp1OyhWJyUAIROYDDGoA7swoHoAITIADqlIQ5KseAq+QdTAgbGYBepRvkcnxhLzDYKxSgPuyuQHJUMIAgBciOXyRWgbhF8h7RJY7E4IAAahoThAGGuOFrDP351BqTdEdhrbyBNhaEuV3mxBIQJJt2xdwxn1I+ifB+fbnuP0dD5ZZhSSZICVXVhDxAa8dFWcZ-E1EBglCCIDw3X9R1PalLTAeDQKoe94kfURxCkeDEPWAJUM2ciX0kbC53-fDCNvCBhBFIA)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that *inside* the `runTypeCallback` body, `callback`'s currently type isn't restricted to one `T` inference or the other - instead it is both.

If you hover on `callback` in your editor, you can see it infers this type:

```js
(object: any) => string | boolean
```

Which fails `type1` because it contains `string`, and fails `type2` because of `boolean`.

You will have to assert one or the other, or the final type, which would be a supertype of the actual type, so it should work.

Just add:

`as ReturnType<TypesCallbacks[T]>` at the end of `return`, like so:

```js
    public runTypeCallback<T extends keyof TypesCallbacks>(id: T): ReturnType<TypesCallbacks[T]> {
        const callback = this.callbackMap[id];

        return callback('zz') as ReturnType<TypesCallbacks[T]>;
    }

}
```

You can see it working [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEDOyDeAUMicgORhYQCMZAXMgEYD2zANhHCADTGkVUATPWQ4wUUAHNeAX0KFK2NFRwBhOGzaNEAazwBeAnxIBtHRHTJQyc%20mYxl2HAF0GACmaMAVhARgGXOgAlMj6AHyOuGYWzgDchDLxhAhscDh4GNgAClDMAG7AACbQRsbImBJ5cJDICBpaugCycJgMmbjqmtoIeqFGpAPIijTunj5%20IeHI8Gw4ELyDpMOCo96%20YJMRFLhgZAukifIDmACujGzACMhQJyDtnQ09ADyoyBAAHpAghXi29pFqerdPRhNxFNpBBgAJQgYBOUDuVBeKgewJwJlQzgiREWJAQzBAYlqQN0fTAAAtgDgAHR1LpNFomIpxI64qCw%20EgYn0npuMgAL35ZBCaWQMLhCPayKcqN06MxYXiAzkCWSBKJFXyRWgbSoOS1xSgfRAEAA7pF9QVDW4gkl8YSwExWBwuAA1DQnCAMFjsThcwyaq3Qak3RHYWW8gTYWi2tUO0TiKTutiehhiCQgSR9QPaqAh273EmR5bC%20JAA).

Comment: It feels super weird that TypeScript is able to infer the correct callback type in the second case, but cannot infer the return type. Like... return type is a part of the callback type...

Comment: I agree. There might be more to this I'm not aware of, or I might be misinterpreting the cause